# Download PDF through HTML Content that is an output of a Function (Oracle APEX)

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, html-to-pdf

I have a packaged function that returns a CLOB data based on a parameter. That CLOB data is returned through an pl/sql Dynamic Content region. The entire CSS and HTML Tags along with data are stored in the function's CLOB return variable which returns the desired report.

Is there any way for me to be able to use this function in such a way that it will automatically download the report as PDF in the same parameterized way but from a Classic or Interactive report?

EXAMPLE OF FUNCTION:

```
FUNCTION FNC_REPORT (P_ID NUMBER)
RETURN CLOB
IS
V_RET CLOB;
BEGIN
SELECT '<TABLE><TR><TD>'||TABLE_COLUMN||'</TD></TR></TABLE>' INTO V_RET
FROM TABLE WHERE ID = P_ID;
RETURN V_RET;
END;
```

EXAMPLE OF PL/SQL DYNAMIC CONTENT:

```
HTP.P(FNC_REPORT(:PAGE_ITEM_ID));
```

WHAT I WANT TO DO NOW IN A CLASSIC OR INTERACTIVE REPORT:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, FNC_REPORT(ID) DOWNLOAD_PDF_REPORT /* DOWNLOAD THROUGHT THIS COLUMN */
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: You can create a REST endpoint using ORDS to achieve this.

Comment: Can you please further elaborate or point me to a source of how this works? I am new to this subject.